# Mongo: find element (id) in Array of Id's

Tags: php, mongodb

I have an ID, and I want to get all documents that has this ID in array.
[image]

How can i get all documents that:

`my_ID` in `{recipients.ids}`

I think this is something like the "opposite" to $in.

Thanks.

Comment: `array( "recipients.ids" => "591c906baced92bd0a8b4567" )`. To match the document where the array contains an element matching the value in that property. Note also it's a "string" and not an `ObjectId`, which points to an error elsewhere in your code. See ["Dot Notation"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) for the general reference

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, this should do it:

```
db.your_collection.find({'ids.recipients': 'the_id_you_look_for'})
```